# How to permanently delete a table name

Tags: apache-superset

I have some csv files. I'm deleting csv table, after I'm trying to upload another data set with the name table name as before, but I'm getting the error such as "the table is existing".

I've researched google and superset documentation, but I couldn't find any way to delete table name permanently.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 3):

When creating new table, if you choose replace option in the table exists tab, you can upload table with the same name.